# Localizing MMC SnapInSettings

Tags: c#, mmc, mmc3

I'm trying to localize

```
[SnapInSettings("GUID",
    DisplayName = ApplicationName, <-- this
    Description = ApplicationDescription, <-- this
    Vendor = VenderName, <-- this
    UseCustomHelp = true)]
```

Issue i'm running into is that these get set during compile time.
and thus Resources.ApplicationName can't be used.

I've searched the first 10 pages of any google result i get and found some references to localized vs non localized descriptions but never a sample or example.

IS there anyone out there that has done this before?
all i really care about is localizing the description.

Comment: Noone? so sad. i guess MMC is a forgotten art form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What i ended up doing is installing the snap-in through a WiX installer.
Then in the installer write the registry entries according to the locale of the system.

that seems to do the trick